# MY Angular - Access to XMLHttpRequest Blocked by CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Present

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

So basically im making a springboot application the server side is
fine but on the angular side im running into a cors error which is
saying the HttpRequest is being blocked by CORS Im really struggling
with this and have looked through many tutorials hoping to find a fix
I'm gonna paste my codes down below and if anyone has a clue as to why
I' m getting this error please help me fix it cheers none of the data from the server side is being displayed and the CORS error is the main reason.

Heres the Angular code:

```
<h2>Lecturers</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let lecturer of lecturers">
        <td>{{ lecturer.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ lecturer.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ lecturer.email }}</td>
        <td>
            <button (click)="updateLecturer(lecturer)">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`lecturers.component.ts` class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lecturers',
  templateUrl: './lecturers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lecturers.component.css']
})
export class LecturersComponent implements OnInit {
  lecturers: any[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchLecturers();
  }

  fetchLecturers(): void {
    this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:8081/lecturers').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.lecturers = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }

  updateLecturer(lecturer: any) {
    // Redirect to edit page with lecturer id in URL
    this.router.navigate(['/lecturers/edit', lecturer.id]);
  }
}
```

Here'ss my server-side code.

lecturer controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;


import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/lecturers")
public class LecturerController {
    private final LecturerService lecturerService;

    public LecturerController(LecturerService lecturerService) {
        this.lecturerService = lecturerService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Lecturer> getAllLecturers() {
        return lecturerService.getAllLecturers();
    }

    // Create a new lecturer
    @PostMapping
    public Lecturer createLecturer(@Valid @RequestBody Lecturer lecturer) {
        return lecturerService.createLecturer(lecturer);
    }

    // Update an existing lecturer
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Lecturer updateLecturer(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody Lecturer lecturer) throws NotFoundException {
        return lecturerService.updateLecturer(id, lecturer);
    }

    // Search for Lecturers by taxBand and salaryScale
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Lecturer>> searchLecturersByTaxBandAndSalaryScale(@RequestParam("taxBand") String taxBand, @RequestParam("salaryScale") int salaryScale) {
        List<Lecturer> lecturers = lecturerService.searchLecturersByTaxBandAndSalaryScale(taxBand, salaryScale);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(lecturers);
    }
}
```

`CorsConfig` class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;


@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors), in order to allow all origins, you can remove `.allowedOrigins("*")` and instead just write

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}
```

}